# How to redirect to a different page after form submission?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms

Right now after submitting my product submission form it just stays in the same page - and I would like to redirect it to a page like: `example.com/profile` after submitting the form. It's a POST method:

```
:method:POST
:path:/dash/product/edit/
:scheme:https
```

It's a huge form but here is the beginning:

```
<!-- Product Submission Form -->
<form method="post" action="" id="wcv-product-edit" class="wcv-form wcv-formvalidator">
```

and the end of the form:

```
<?php WCVendors_Pro_Product_Form::form_data( $object_id, $post_status ); ?>
            <?php WCVendors_Pro_Product_Form::save_button( $title ); ?>
```

Is there any possibility to actually redirect to `example.com/profile` after submitting this form?

Answer (score 0):

Headers is one way to do it.

```
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

[W3schools sample](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp)

[PHP headers documents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: I've tried placing this code inside of my form but it completely redirects the form to another page - I want only to redirect after submission..

Answer (score 0):

I would checkout [wp_redirect](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)

If the form's post request is handled on the same page, you would add your redirect at the end of the code that handles the request and not at the end of your form itself.

Something like...

```
if( ! empty( $_POST ) ){
 // your code to process request
 wp_redirect( 'http://yoursite.com' );
 exit; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your form action is blank. that means you are processing the form on the same page on which the form page and that the page has .php extension.

so the top of the page will have this code or as per the code provided by you

you can try adding it after your code.

```
<?php WCVendors_Pro_Product_Form::form_data( $object_id, $post_status ); ?>
<?php header('Location: http://yoursite.com/profile'); ?>
<?php WCVendors_Pro_Product_Form::save_button( $title ); ?>
```